# Merge two rows or more tables into single row based on a column using LINQ C# in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two tables and I want output of both tables in one result set using Linq in C# in excel format.

I have sample tables here - first table is `Student` which looks like this:

| ID | Roll No |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |

And my second table is `Marks`. In this table for one user there may be multiple records:

| Id | Paper Code | IAT | IAP | ET | EP | Viva | Student_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1101 | 54 | 68 | 52 | 68 | 89 | 1 |
| 2 | 1101 | 65 | 98 | 87 | 54 | 63 | 2 |
| 3 | 1102 | 88 | 97 | 56 | 87 | 74 | 1 |
| 4 | 1102 | 52 | 68 | 54 | 75 | 90 | 2 |
| 5 | 1103 | 56 | 45 | 98 | 45 | 65 | 1 |
| 6 | 1103 | 65 | 92 | 87 | 98 | 72 | 2 |

I want the result in a single row for every user in a excel sheetsheet as shown below.

| Id | Roll No | Paper Code | IAT | IAP | ET | EP | Viva | Paper Code | IAT | IAP | ET | EP | Viva | Paper Code | IAT | IAP | ET | EP | Viva |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 1101 | 54 | 68 | 52 | 68 | 89 | 1102 | 88 | 97 | 56 | 87 | 74 | 1103 | 56 | 45 | 98 | 45 | 65 |
| 2 | 102 | 1101 | 65 | 98 | 87 | 54 | 63 | 1102 | 52 | 68 | 54 | 75 | 90 | 1103 | 65 | 92 | 87 | 98 | 72 |

Here is my code to download excel. It not Showing the output as desired.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
 protected void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string year = YearSemList.SelectedValue;
            string courseName = CourseList.SelectedValue;
            string examName = ExamList.SelectedValue;
            string examType = ExamTypeList.SelectedValue;
            var myList = (
                            from S in db.Student
                            where S.year.Trim() == year && S.CourseName.Trim() == courseName && S.ExamName.Trim() == examName && S.ExamType.Trim() == examType
                            join M in db.Marks on S.Id equals M.Student_Id
                            select new {
                                S,M
                            }
                         ).ToList();
            var grps = (from d in myList
                        group d by d.S.RollNumber
                        into grp
                        
                       select new
                       {
                           RollNumber = grp.Key,
                           PaperCode = grp.Select(d2 => d2.M.PaperCode).ToArray(),
                           PaperName = grp.Select(d2 => d2.M.PaperName).ToArray(),
                           ExternalTheory = grp.Select(d2 => d2.M.ExternalTheory).ToArray(),
                           ExternalPrac = grp.Select(d2 => d2.M.ExternalPrac).ToArray(),
                           IAT = grp.Select(d2 => d2.M.IAT).ToArray(),
                           IAP = grp.Select(d2 => d2.M.IAP).ToArray(),
                           viva = grp.Select(d2 => d2.M.viva).ToArray(),
                       }).OrderBy(x=>x.RollNumber).ToList();

            int rows = grps.Max(grp => grp.PaperCode.Length);
            ///code excel
            try
            {
                using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Students");
                    var currentRow = 5; var i = 1;
                    #region Header
                    // output columns
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "Sr. No";
                    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                    {
                       
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "RollNo";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "PaperCode";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "PaperName";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "External Theory";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "External Practical";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "Intenal Theory";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "Intenal Practical";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i++).Value = "Viva";
                       
                    }


                    #endregion

                    #region Body
                    currentRow = 5; var m = 1;
                    for (int a = 0; a < rows; a++)
                    {
                        currentRow++;
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = i;
                        foreach (var student in grps)
                        {
                            //var j = 3;
                            
                           
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.RollNumber;
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.PaperCode;
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.PaperName;
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.ExternalTheory;
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.ExternalPrac;
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.IAT;
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.IAP;
                            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, m++).Value = student.viva;
                            i++;
                        }
                        m = 1;
                    }
                    #endregion
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GV.xlsx");

                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                        //var content = stream.ToArray();
                        stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Is something not working? What is the question exactly?

Comment: It not Showing the output as desired.